# What is the connection (if any) between Knot Theory and Fluid Dynamics?

Tags: knot-theory, fluid-dynamics

I've heard there is a connection to physics, but I'm unsure about any specific connection to fluid dynamics.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! To help your Readers understand the Question better, more context would be helpful.  Broad and speculative discussions are not the goal of this Community.  Please see the [Help Center FAQ](http://math.stackexchange.com/help) on how to participate, esp. asking good questions.

Comment: This question is too broad.  Also, [did you try Googling it](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=knot+theory+and+fluid+dynamics)?

Answer (score 0):

there is a link between fluid mixing and braid theory, braid theory is a branch of knot theory as there is a way to turn all knots into a braid.

Imagine having a container with some fluid in, and three prongs in the fluid that can swap positions, if you plotted out on a graph time going downwards and each prong's horizontal position on the same x axis you get a braid and from this interesting properties occur.